# Reputation displays incorrectly on another user's profile as a moderator

Tags: bug, reputation

Looking at [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing?tab=reputation&sort=post)'s reputation on CGCC, I see +191 for today (as of the time of writing):

[image]

These clearly don't add up to 191. They add up to 190, which is what I see when I open this page in incognito (in fact everything is identical *except* for the 191), and several users can confirm that they see 190 when looking at it. I have only managed to reproduce this on my computer while logged in, thus I believe this is an issue with mod tools / something.

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or something else going on here? (The time and graph tab also show 191 and the breakdown adds up to 190)

Comment: One thing of note: a couple of days ago I got +201 rep in a day, due to a bug with undownvoting. This was corrected yesterday. Additionally, I downvoted a spam answer, later removed and refunding me the +1 rep, yesterday, so I did gain +1 (although also lost it)